# From gpx to line segment 1Km using ArcGIS 10

Tags: arcgis-10.0, gps, gpx

I have gpx files containg points with attribute data such as time and date. I'd like to convert them into lines, and that is not a problem, but what I want to do is create 1Km segments with time and date attribute.
I'm using Arcgis 10.2

Thanks
[image]

Comment: How will the points be connected to make line segments? Are these points pairs that are 1km apart? A mapped example or drawing of what you want to do would be key, here.

Comment: Hi thank you for your reply.

I'll try to be more clear, I have gpx points with date and elevation. Since I'd like to do an animated application thorugh Arcgis.com I want to connect them using segments 1Km long and then attach the date time to the segment so I can use it in the data aware shape. I tried points to lines, using date_time but It does'n work.